# In User Agent strings, what does "AskTbTRL" denote?

Tags: web-crawlers, user-agent

Here are a bunch of examples:

http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/listings.asp?search=asktbtrl

I would've guessed an Ask.com-related bot, but apparently not according to their [FAQ](http://www.ask.com/staticcontent/about/helpcenter/about_helpcenter_webmaster#9).

Comment: Your link says it's AskTbTRL2 btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search shows that it's the user agent for the ask.com toolbar.

Comment: Ah, I'd been googling "AskTbTRL" which revealed nothing. Adding "2" to the end did the trick. Thanks

Comment: I didn't add the two to the end and I still gt the correct result. You should try actually clicking on some of the results next time.

Comment: And you should try looking up the word "nothing". Google gives different results to different users. In my case, there were zero results returned. Thanks anyway for the pro-tip.